# i want to scrape data using python script

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-3.4

I have written python script to scrape data from http://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket-stats/icc-rankings/batsmen-rankings 
It is a list of 100 players and I successfully scraped this data. The problem is, when i run script instead of scraping data just one time it scraped the same data 3 times.

```html
<div class="cb-col cb-col-100 cb-font-14 cb-lst-itm text-center">
  <div class="cb-col cb-col-16 cb-rank-tbl cb-font-16">1</div>
  <div class="cb-col cb-col-50 cb-lst-itm-sm text-left">
    <div class="cb-col cb-col-33">
      <div class="cb-col cb-col-50">
        <span class=" cb-ico" style="position:absolute;"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;–
      </div>
      <div class="cb-col cb-col-50">
        <img src="http://i.cricketcb.com/i/stats/fw/50x50/img/faceImages/2250.jpg" class="img-responsive cb-rank-plyr-img">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cb-col cb-col-67 cb-rank-plyr">
      <a class="text-hvr-underline text-bold cb-font-16" href="/profiles/2250/steven-smith" title="Steven Smith's Profile">Steven Smith</a>
      <div class="cb-font-12 text-gray">AUSTRALIA</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cb-col cb-col-17 cb-rank-tbl">906</div>
  <div class="cb-col cb-col-17 cb-rank-tbl">1</div>
</div>
```

And here is python script which i write scrap each player data.

```js
import sys,requests,csv,io
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = "http://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket-stats/icc-rankings/batsmen-rankings"
r = requests.get(url)
r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

maindiv = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "text-center"})
for div in maindiv:
 print(div.text)
```

but instead of scraping the data once, it scrapes the same data 3 times.

Where can I make changes to get data just one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the table and look for the divs in that:

```
maindiv = soup.select("#batsmen-tests div.text-center")
for div in maindiv:
    print(div.text)
```

Your original output and that above gets all the text from the divs as one line which is not really useful, if you just want the player names:

```
anchors = soup.select("#batsmen-tests div.cb-rank-plyr a")
for a in anchors:
    print(a.text)
```

A quick and easy way to get the data in a nice csv format is to just get text from each child:

```
maindiv = soup.select("#batsmen-tests div.text-center")
for d in maindiv[1:]:
    row_data = u",".join(s.strip() for s in filter(None, (t.find(text=True, recursive=False) for t in d.find_all())))
    if row_data:
        print(row_data)
```

Now you get output like:

```
# rank, up/down, name, country, rating, best rank
1,–,Steven Smith,AUSTRALIA,906,1
2,–,Joe Root,ENGLAND,878,1
3,–,Kane Williamson,NEW ZEALAND,876,1
4,–,Hashim Amla,SOUTH AFRICA,847,1
5,–,Younis Khan,PAKISTAN,845,1
6,–,Adam Voges,AUSTRALIA,802,5
7,–,AB de Villiers,SOUTH AFRICA,802,1
8,–,Ajinkya Rahane,INDIA,785,8
9,2,David Warner,AUSTRALIA,772,3
10,–,Alastair Cook,ENGLAND,770,2
11,1,Misbah-ul-Haq,PAKISTAN,764,6
```

As opposed to:

```
PositionPlayerRatingBest Rank
Player
1    –Steven SmithAUSTRALIA9061
2    –Joe RootENGLAND8781
3    –Kane WilliamsonNEW ZEALAND8761
4    –Hashim AmlaSOUTH AFRICA8471
5    –Younis KhanPAKISTAN8451
6    –Adam VogesAUSTRALIA8025
```

Comment: @hrmalik, no worries, I added how to separate the data into  a more usable format.

Comment: I suppose to do same task but i couldn't find a way to do it like data in comma separated values but you are awesome just hit the goal with your trick excellent :*

Comment: i want to learn python skills same like you have. If you have any source to teach me or know any best tutorials point where i can get best material to learn python just tell me

Answer (score -1):

The reason you get output three times is because the website has three categories you have to select it and then accordingly you can use it.

Simplest way of doing it with your code would be to add just one line

```
import sys,requests,csv,io
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket-stats/icc-rankings/batsmen-   rankings"
r = requests.get(url)
r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

specific_div = soup.find_all("div", {"id": "batsmen-tests"})
maindiv = specific_div[0].find_all("div", {"class": "text-center"})
for div in maindiv:
    print(div.text)
```

This will give similar reuslts with just test batsmen, for other output just change the "id" in specific_div line.

Comment: This is exactly what my code is doing bar the unnecessary use of find_all

Comment: No it doesn't it gives just the 100 entries, yours give 300 results. That bis the reason I am writing one extra find_all

Comment: No mine does not give 300. It gives 100 and gives them in usable format

Comment: Okay, my bad but if you will see the question was not how to make it usable but was to avoid getting 300 results and to get just 100. That's what it does.

Comment: That is the first part of my answer, the logic is exactly the same as yours, it looks in the table with the id `batsmen-tests` bar as I mentioned unnecessary find_all calls as we are not looking for multiple tables

Comment: @Neeraj Komuravalli you both guys are fabulous. I am start learning python just right now and as i am junior in this field i am very glad to have senior like you to help me in this filed. Just excellent work by both of you :)